# trying to download jpg images using wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to download jpg images from one of our suppliers. I know the image locations so for example I use:

wget http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/SPM/450/SPM1511-450.jpg

This was working fine for a while. But I started getting check certificate issues.
When I added the "check_certificate = off" >> , the down load would be corrupt. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Sounds like your http request is redirected to https

Answer (score 0):

That link goes to a login so I imagine your wget can only fail, you'd better look into curl and login options.

Answer (score 0):

You should bypass the authentication step first.
The link you provided is not reachable without authenticating first.